# Contact details on a mobile site

Tags: mobile, contact-page

On the mobile version of a site I am working on I would like the user to be able to download a contact card straight into their address book.

Is this possible with microformats (or anything for that matter) and which phone browsers / phones support what?

I have spent some time researching the issue and haven't come up with anything conclusive.

Comment: I think this'll do better at SO. On quick search, [this existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518567/embed-iphone-contact-on-page-click-link) has overlap.

Comment: I was going to stick it up on SO but since I didn't know what technology I would even be using to do this I figured it too vague.

Comment: Understandable. That's just based on my own interpretation of the sites' differences. "How do I build X" generally leans toward SO for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen anything suggesting this can be done directly, ie. tap a link and get prompted to create a contact, but here's a [somewhat hacky workaround](http://thecodetrain.co.uk/2009/11/adding-a-vcard-to-your-iphone-address-book-from-a-web-page/) someone came up with a couple years ago. It's more work than it *should* be, but within reason if it's still not possible and this is important to you.

The condensed version is that you create a link to a vCard on your site somewhere, for everybody, but then do a bit of basic browser sniffing via PHP(or whatever) for mobile access. If detected, replace the aforementioned link with a link to a quick form the visitor can use to have the vCard e-mailed to them. Once received, they can use the phone's native support for importing them.