# How can I email a vCard to users who are unable to download it?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I have created vCards for the people in my business, and they are great for users on standard browsers; however, users browsing on a mobile device (notably iPhone) are unable to download and view my vCard.

Is there a service that I can direct them to that will allow them to receive an email containing my vCard, or is there a simple way I can set this up myself? I am running my site on WordPress, and initial attempts have failed spectacularly.

I'd like for them to be given the option to perform either action, but have the predominant action more prominently visible (probably via user agent detection). Something along the lines of:

> It looks like you're on an iPhone! It's a bummer they can't download vCards, but if you enter your email address, we'll wrap one up and send it your way!
>
> *Don't worry, we won't send you junk email. Heck, we don't even save your email address!*
>
> ---
>
> `enter-your@email.com`
>
> ---
>
> *Think you've got it all figured out? Fine, [download the vCard instead!](http:///)*

If you know of a service or simple-to-implement PHP library (or WordPress plug-in), please let me know! If not, let me know what the best solution to this problem is!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Contact details on a mobile site](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19773/contact-details-on-a-mobile-site)

Comment: Can you build (and send) multipart/mixed e-mail with PHPMailer?

Comment: Did you try the links in my answer where they useful?

Comment: I managed to cobble something together, and it's working fine for my purposes! You can see it in action [here](http://www.thegamestudio.net/vcards).

Comment: _I remembered some of the libraries I used._

I managed to cobble something together using the classes from [PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/), and it's working fine for my purposes! You can see it in action [here](http://www.thegamestudio.net/vcards).

Comment: Just a note that whatever mailing library you use to send the vCard be sure to send to Gmail, Yahoo, AOL, and an Outlook account to make sure the headers are set properly and the email isn't getting flagged by spam filters. Outlooks junk filter especially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most flexible solution I've found is [PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/).

A few things to note: You'll have to check with your webhost and determine if you can use `sendmail` from their server, or if you'll have to use an SMTP server elsewhere. That will be the biggest block from actually sending your email.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try [vCard Makers website](http://vcardmaker.com/) to generate them, or take a look at this article about generating [iPhone, Android and BB compatible vCards/Qrcodes](http://learnyii.blogspot.com/2011/04/vcard-qr-code-iphone-android-blackberry.html)

Comment: I already have a vCard created, I just need to get it mailed to folks.

Comment: Ok, here's another email library used in quite a few applications http://swiftmailer.org